# ADO possibly ignoring error from SQL Server

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ado

Here is some SQL...

```sql
UPDATE table1 SET date = GETDATE() WHERE id = @id

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN;
    THROW 50004, 'Row not updated.', 1;
END
```

If I run this in Management Studio with a bogus id, I get...

> (0 row(s) affected) Msg 50004, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   MyStoredProcedure, Line 50 Row not updated.

If I run this from ASP Classic, the `Err.Number` is 0 and the connection's errors collection is empty.

If I remove the `UPDATE` statement, then the error is registered.

Why is ADO ignoring the error after an update?

Comment: Saying *"ADO ignoring error"* is a bit presumptuous, it's more likely that the SQL Server provider that ADODB is using doesn't trigger the `THROW` statement for some reason. Remember just because it works from SSMS doesn't mean it will work from ADODB first time, but testing queries in SSMS is a start. Just try not to jump to conclusions until you have conclusive proof.

Comment: Do you call `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to make sure you get the right result for `@@ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: Yes, the question is presumptuous. Good thinking. I worked out that `SET NOCOUNT ON;` fixes the problem. However, even without it, `@@ROWCOUNT` still works when called from ASP - and I proved this by returning its correct value to ASP via an OUT parameter on the stored procedure. So I think my "hypothesis" is still not refuted.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the beginning of the stored procedure.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx), it says...

> SET NOCOUNT ON prevents the sending of DONE_IN_PROC messages to the
>   client for each statement in a stored procedure.

So, perhaps a `DONE_IN_PROC` message is resulting in the subsequent error being skipped.